# Function Modifying a Character String

Tags: string, r, character

I need a function that will take input as a character string (BLANK) and print out the following:

```
"Hello BLANK World"
```

i.e., world("seven") prints out `"Hello seven World"`

I'm very confused on how to work with character strings in R.

Answer (score 5):

You want the function `paste`

```
world <- function(x) paste("Hello", x, "World")
```

Comment: +1: `paste` is the first function to learn if you're unfamiliar with character string manipulation.

Answer (score 5):

Or...

```
 x <- "seven"
 sprintf("Hello %s World", x)
```

In other words no need for a `world` function as that's what `sprintf` does.

Answer (score 4):

There's a tutorial on working with character strings in R [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/basic-data-types/character).

R does not have a "concatenate" operator as many other languages do. So for example:

```
x <- "A"
y <- "B"

x + y            # Like javascript? No - does NOT produce "AB"
# Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator

x || y           # Like SQL? No - does NOT produce "AB"
# Error in x || y : invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'

x . y            # Like PHP? No - does NOT produce "AB"
# Error: unexpected symbol in "x ."

paste(x,y, sep="")
# [1] "AB"
```

As @Matthew says, you must use `paste(...)` to concatenate. Read the documentation, though, about default separators.

Comment: You could write your own string concatenate function `"+.String" <- function(e1, e2) paste0(e1, e2); "+.String" <- function(e1, e2){paste0(e1,e2)}; as.String("hey ") + as.String("you")
`

Comment: Weird - that first +.String should have been `as.String <- function(x){class(x) <- "String"; x}`

Comment: There is %+% operator for concatenating strings. Look at the `stringi` package :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringi` package:

```
require(stringi)
## Loading required package: stringi
"a"%+%"b"
## [1] "ab"
```