# Change names of observations in a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to rename 9000 observations in my dataframe by trimming off the end '_C1_A1' and adding a prefix 'RNA_'

```
df
ID                   MP Value
FFP16-000123_C1_A1       -1
FFP16-000124_C1_A1        0
FFP16-000125_C1_A1        1

df
ID                    MP Value
RNA_FFP16-000123         -1
RNA_FFP16-000124          0 
RNA_FFP16-000125          1
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to modify a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20481621/903061) or [Add text to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31471220/903061), and [String processing in R (find and replace)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27012107/903061).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To substitute only the '_C1_A1' suffix, use the functions *paste0* and *gsub*:

```
df$ID <- paste0("RNA_", gsub("_C1_A1", "", df$ID))
```

To make the same change for all suffixes beginning with an underscore, you can use the regular expression "_.*" as the first argument to gsub:

```
df$ID <- paste0("RNA_", gsub("_.*", "", df$ID))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That almost did it, but my data has many different suffixes (ie C1_A1, C2_A1, C1_A3, etc.). Is there a way to specify the # of characters to trim rather than the exact characters.

Comment: I think the simplest approach in this case will be to simply drop everything following the first underscore... please see my revised answer and let me know if it doesn't solve the problem.